# ERROR 1451 (23000): Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, constraints

I have the following code...

```
drop table if exists Route;
drop table if exists Profit;
drop table if exists Airport;

create table Airport( 
Airport_code varchar(3), 
Airport_name varchar(30),  
Country varchar(30),
primary key(Airport_code)
); 

create table Profit(
Year int,
Profit_factor double,
primary key(Year)
);

create table Route(
Route_id int not null auto_increment,
Departure_airport_code varchar(3),
Arrival_airport_code varchar(3),
Year int, 
Route_price double default 0,  
primary key(Route_id),
foreign key(Arrival_airport_code) references Airport(Airport_code),
foreign key(Departure_airport_code) references Airport(Airport_code),
foreign key(Year) references Profit(Year)
);
```

When i execute this code for the first time it runs successfully without error, it gives me a warning for each of the drop statements though..
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.03 sec)

The actual problem occurs when i try to execute the same code for the second time, which theoretically should not cause any error. But i get..
ERROR 1451 (23000): Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

I am not deleting the parent table first, which causes this error. I do not want to use set foreign_key_checks or cascade statements but rather find out the actual underlying cause here.

Thanks

Comment: I tested the code above. I can run it repeatedly. I think the error is coming from some other code that you have not shown.

Comment: @BillKarwin besides the fact that my relational model contains more tables, these 3 are the first 3 tables in my model so i guess the other tables should not matter since im trying to execute only this part of the code separately. I am still getting the same error when i try to run it repeatedly.

Comment: Do any of the other tables have a foreign key reference to any of these three? You can't DROP TABLE while another table needs it to exist because of a foreign key is referencing it.

Comment: Yes, but those tables which depened on any of these 3 tables are deleted before deleting these 3 tables.